# FFMPEG library rotates video after trim automatically

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to trim recorded video with **ffmpeg library** .
Built with NDK, all ok.
Then I try to trim video my video-trimmer.c .
Video trimmed after called command. But rotates video :( 
I lose many days, however could not solve this problem.
These are arguments which I used:

```
arguments[0] = "ffmpeg";
arguments[1] = "-i";
arguments[2] = in;
arguments[3] = "-ss";
arguments[4] = start;
arguments[5] = "-t";
arguments[6] = duration;
arguments[7] = "-acodec";
arguments[8] = "copy";
arguments[9] = "-vcodec";
arguments[10] = "copy";
```

Comment: Does the video stream contain rotate metadata? The output of `ffmpeg -i input` will display this info.

Comment: Hello LordNeckbeard. 
You can find logs from this txt file :
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/toftp4f2ziqg4ee/logs.txt?dl=0
P.S I do not have experience with ffmpeg. It is first time. So I copied all logs.

Comment: Unfortunately your log did not contain the complete `ffmpeg` console output. Also, the 0.6 release branch is old so please update if possible.

Comment: Hi LordNeckbeard. I downloaded ffmpeg4android from sourceforge, but could not find with NDK-BUILD command. 
My OS - Windows 
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, (cat jni/ffmpeg/RELEASE), ...) failed.